# Lisp Move Elements in a List

Tags: list, lisp

I have a list of the form:

```
(or a b c (and d e) f g (and h i) (==> x y))
```

and I like to move the sublists beginning with `and` after the `or` like this:

```
(or (and d e) (and h i) a b c f g (==> x y))
```

How can I do this? I'm not sure what's the best way since it's a list and I can't just put an element whatever I want, like I can with other data structures.

Answer (score 1):

```
? (stable-sort (rest '(or a b c (and d e) f g (and h i) (==> x y)))
               (lambda (x y)
                 (and (consp x) (eq (first x) 'and))))
((AND H I) (AND D E) A B C F G (==> X Y))
```

Comment: Thanks, but the initial OR where is?